# kotlin notifyDataSetChanged does not update the view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've begun to use kotlin a few days ago and I'm getting a problem with a recyclerView. When I do call the notifiyDataSetChanged method of my adapter the view does not update. (I used the debugger and my variable "usersList" is updated but not the view. Here's my Adapter class :

```
private class RankingAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RankingViewHolder>() {
        var usersList : MutableList<User?>? = mutableListOf()
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RankingViewHolder {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.ranking_item_layout, parent,false) as LinearLayout
            return RankingViewHolder(v)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return usersList?.size ?: 0
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RankingViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val user : User? = usersList?.get(position)
            holder.rank.text = (usersList?.indexOf(user)).toString()
            holder.name.text = user?.firstName
            holder.points.text = user?.score.toString()
        }

        fun setUsers(users : List<User?>) {
            usersList?.clear()
            usersList?.addAll(users)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

and the method where setUsers(users) is called

```
private fun displayRanking(users : List<User>) {
        visibleLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        errorImageView.visibility = View.GONE
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        val logedInUser = SaveSharedPreference.getLogedInUser(context)
        userRank.text = (adapter.usersList?.indexOf(logedInUser)).toString()
        userName.text = logedInUser.firstName
        userPoints.text = logedInUser.score.toString()
        adapter.setUsers(users)
    }
```

Comment: Did you make `recyclerview.adapter = adapter`

Comment: yes : adapter = RankingAdapter() and
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1:** Try this

```
fun setUsers(users : List<User?>) {
        usersList?.clear()
        usersList?.addAll(users)
}
```

Where you set recyclerView Adapter:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManger(this, LinearLayoutManager.Vertical, false)
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

And in your displayRanking function:

```
private fun displayRanking(users : List<User>) {
    visibleLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    errorImageView.visibility = View.GONE
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    val logedInUser = SaveSharedPreference.getLogedInUser(context)
    userRank.text = (adapter.usersList?.indexOf(logedInUser)).toString()
    userName.text = logedInUser.firstName
    userPoints.text = logedInUser.score.toString()

    adapter.setUsers(users)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

---

Try calling **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** in your **displayRanking function** after calling **adapter.setUsers(users)** and delete notifyDataSetChanged() in your Adapter class.

Comment: the problem is still there

Comment: @andrc I edited my answer, can you try this?

Comment: @andrc I just want to tell you that you should move this recyclerView.layoutManager right above where you wrote recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter). Then you'll still be able to use notifyDataSetChanged in displayRanking() function. This way your recylcerView will have layoutManager from its initialization and not only later when you first change dataset with displayRanking().