# Android : Cannot update RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am developing an Android application in Kotlin and I implemented a RecyclerView.

The two parameters that are added to the `parametersList` are displayed, but when I press the `TEST` button, the RecyclerView is not updated! I don't understand my mistake, can you help me?

Here is my adapter:

```
class CustomAdapter(private val parameterList: List<Parameter>, private val onClick: ((selectedParameter: Parameter) -> Unit)? = null) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun showItem(parameter: Parameter, onClick: ((selectedParameter: Parameter) -> Unit)? = null) {
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.parameterName).text = parameter.parameterName
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.parameterValue).text = parameter.parameterValue as CharSequence?

            if(onClick != null) {
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    onClick(parameter)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.parameter_text, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.showItem(parameterList[position], onClick)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return parameterList.size
    }

}
```

My activity:

```
class NFCActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc)

        buttonTest.setOnClickListener() {

            parametersList = parametersList + ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
            rv_parameters2.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        rv_parameters2.adapter = CustomAdapter(parametersList) { item ->
            println("------------------OnClick------------------")
        }
        rv_parameters2.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    }


    private var parametersList : List<Parameter> = listOf<Parameter> (
            ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C"),
            ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
    )

    companion object {
        fun getStartIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            return Intent(context, NFCActivity::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

parameter_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parameterName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/parameter_name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/parameterValue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parameterValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/parameter_value"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/parameterName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/parameterName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_nfc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.ble.NFCActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_parameters2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/parameter_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonTest"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT 1: (following SlothCoding's answer)**

My new activity:

```
class NFCActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc)

        buttonTest.setOnClickListener() {

            parametersList = parametersList + ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
            rv_parameters2.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        rv_parameters2.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        rv_parameters2.adapter = CustomAdapter(parametersList) { item ->
            println("------------------OnClick------------------")
        }
    }

    private var parametersList : List<Parameter> = listOf<Parameter> (
            ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C"),
            ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
    )

    companion object {
        fun getStartIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            return Intent(context, NFCActivity::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2: (following Sekiro's answer)**

**CustomAdapter**

```
class CustomAdapter(private val parameterList: List<Parameter>, private val onClick: ((selectedParameter: Parameter) -> Unit)? = null) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var parameterListLocal: List<Parameter> = parameterList

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun showItem(parameter: Parameter, onClick: ((selectedParameter: Parameter) -> Unit)? = null) {
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.parameterName).text = parameter.parameterName
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.parameterValue).text = parameter.parameterValue as CharSequence?

            if(onClick != null) {
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    onClick(parameter)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.parameter_text, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.showItem(parameterListLocal[position], onClick)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return parameterListLocal.size
    }

    fun addNewList(newList: List<Parameter>){
        parameterListLocal = newList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**NFCActivity**

```
class NFCActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc)

        buttonTest.setOnClickListener() {

            parametersList = parametersList + ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
            (rv_parameters2.adapter as CustomAdapter).addNewList(parametersList)
        }

        rv_parameters2.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        rv_parameters2.adapter = CustomAdapter(parametersList) { item ->
            println("------------------OnClick------------------")
        }
    }

    private var parametersList : List<Parameter> = listOf<Parameter> (
            ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C"),
            ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
    )

    companion object {
        fun getStartIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            return Intent(context, NFCActivity::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer I posted earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545398/14759470

Comment: I tried to do what you advise in the link you gave me but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly did you change in your codE?

Comment: I edited my first question with my new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `buttonTest.setOnClickListener()` where you are updating the list but the adapter knows nothing about the updation of the arraylist, instead pass the new arraylist to the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Try the following

**CustomAdapter**

```
// add this new function

fun addNewList(newList: List<Parameter>){
   parameterList = newList;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

trigger `addNewList` through `buttonTest.setOnClickListener`

```
buttonTest.setOnClickListener() {
       parametersList = parametersList + ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
       (rv_parameters2.adapter as CustomAdapter).addNewList(parametersList)
}
```

Edit:

`notifyDataSetChanged()` is indeed a costly operation and should be replaced with either [`notifyItemInserted`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)) or a better choice would be to use [`ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter)

Comment: I followed your advice and it works! I had to add a `parameterListLocal` attribute in the **CustomAdapter** class but I don't know if it's the best thing to do.

Comment: glad it worked, you dont have to add a new attribute, just update `parameterList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` , Happy coding :)